# Frame Listerner in QMLOgre advancingu

Tags: qml, qt5, ogre

What we have to do in order to add a frame listener in qmlogre lib?
Because if I try to set :

```
m_ogreEngine = new OgreEngine(this);
m_root = m_ogreEngine->startEngine();
m_ogreEngine->setupResources();

m_ogreEngine->activateOgreContext();
//pRenderWindow=m_ogreEngine->getRenderWindow();

createScene();
createFrameListener();

// renderingLoop
m_root->startRendering();

while(true)
{
 Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::messagePump();

  if(pRenderWindow->isClosed())
    std::cout<<"pRenderWindow close"<renderOneFrame())
  std::cout<<"root renderOneFrame"<doneOgreContext();
  emit(ogreInitialized());

  and use the frame listener i ‘ve defined, my Ogre window freezes…
```

Do I realy need to use and defined a frame listener or can i use ogreitem to repaint my scene with new element?

thanks!